# Is there any way I can execute the immediate statement after sleep when I have interrupted the thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Have a look at the following snippet with the comments :

```
try {
  Thread.sleep(20000); // Foo thread sleeps for 20 seconds
  System.out.println("After the sleep statement");
} catch(Exception exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
  }

// It has been 12 seconds since the thread went to sleep and....I interrupt

Foo.interrupt(); // exception gets thrown and the code in the catch block gets executed
```

Is there any way I can execute the next statement after the sleep statement ? I want to awaken the thread at some time and want it to continue it work . Is there any thought/method for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want?

```
try {
  Thread.sleep(20000); // Foo thread sleeps for 20 seconds
  System.out.println("After the sleep statement");
} catch(InterruptedException exc) {
    System.out.println("Sleep was interrupted");
} catch(Exception exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

`sleep()` throws `InterruptedException` when it is interrupted. So `"Sleep was interrupted"` will be printed on `interrupt()` while `"After the sleep statement"` is called only if `sleep()` managed to sleep configured 20 seconds.

If you don't care whether `sleep()` returned normally or thrown and just continue your work, wrap it with empty `try-catch`:

```
public void interruptibleSleep(long millis) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch(InterruptedException exc) {}
}
```

and then instead of `Thread.sleep(20000)` call `interruptibleSleep(20000)`:

```
interruptibleSleep(20000);
System.out.println("After the sleep statement");
```

Comment: _""After the sleep statement") is called only if sleep() managed to sleep configured 20 seconds"_ Isn't there any method that awakes the thread and block continues as if the thread slept for configured 20 seconds ? I mean the statements after thread.sleep

Comment: @Y.E.P: see my `interruptibleSleep()` method

Comment: Does your java have object.wait(long millis)?

Comment: @MartinJames: I don't understand your question, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused. Here's what happens

```
public void run() { 
  // This executes as soon as the thread is run
  try {
     // We decide to sleep for UPTO 20 seconds
     Thread.sleep(20000); 

     // Code here executes ONLY if we managed to sleep for 20 seconds without 
     // interruption

  } catch(InterruptedException exc) {
     // Code here executes ONLY if we were interrupted
  } catch(Exception exc) {
     // This shouldn't ever execute in theory
  }

  // Code here ALWAYS executes after the sleeping (and ONE of the two blocks) 
  // whether or not it was interrupted.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very well phrased paragraph at [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

> An interrupt is an indication to a thread that it should stop what it is doing and do something else. It's up to the programmer to decide exactly how a thread responds to an interrupt, but it is very common for the thread to terminate. This is the usage emphasized in this lesson.

Stopping and staring threads reliably is an important part of designing concurrent applications.  And even though you *could* repurpose interrupts to do whatever you want, your code will be more reliable and easier to maintain for others if you leave interrupt for it's most common purpose - requesting that the thread exit.  This is something you will probably want to do if the user decides to shutdown the app before the 20 second timeout is finished.

So how to solve the original problem - allowing one thread to indicate to another that it is time to get to work.  The class below shows how a CountDownLatch might be used to solve this problem.

The new Foo:

```
class Foo extends Thread
{

   CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      try
      {
         boolean early = latch.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         System.out.println("Doing work " + (early ? "right away" : "after delay"));
         // do real work here...
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e)
      {
         System.out.println("Interrupt detected. Exiting thread...");
      }
   }

   public void goAhead()
   {
      latch.countDown();
   }
}
```

We get rid of the "Sleep" and replace it with a call to the await method of the latch object.  To make foo do work, invoke:

```
foo.goAhead();  // prints out "Doing work right away"
```

This causes the latch to countdown.  The call to "await" will immediately exit without throwing an exception and returning true.

To shut down foo, use:

```
foo.interrupt();  // prints out "Interrupt detected..."
```

This will cause await to throw an InterruptedException just like sleep.

Or do nothing.  The call to await times out after 20 seconds, does not throw an exception and returns false. Foo prints out "Doing work after delay"

One long term advantage of this design as that while you are "doing work" you may need to call other blocking methods.  Interrupt can still be used to interrupt any of them and help you on your way to shutting down the thread reliably in response to unexpected events.